# How do I fade a procedural clouds on the edges of a bounding box?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have procedural clouds made following Default Cube's [tutorial](https://youtu.be/lCvP917Z8uc), the node group looks like this:

[image: cloud nodes]

The whole thing is bounded by a large cube, and I want to fade the clouds near the edges so that they don't just cut off. Clouds are distributed using the Voronoi texture, so originally, I wanted to do this by adjusting the Voronoi texture using a Separate XYZ node and a color ramp, but it didn't work how I thought it would. How should I do it?

Here is the blend file: [image]

Comment: please provide your blend file so we can improve it

Comment: It is added now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can try it with this setup and tweak a bit the values to your needs:

What it does: a spherical gradient texture influences (multiplies) the value of the clouds so that they "disappear" to the edges of the sphere.

Of course you could do something similar with a box if you prefer box-like-clouds.

[image]

result:

[image]